# Find the power series of $f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ using the power series of a parent function centered at $0$. How can I do this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Work so far:

$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{x}$$

$$e^{-x} = 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots+ \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!} + \cdots$$

$$\frac{1}{x} = 1- (x-1)+(x-1)^2 + \cdots + (-1)^n(x-1)^n + \cdots$$

$$\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \approx [1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}][1-(x-1)+(x-1)^2] $$

Now I'm confused because I have multiplied the two expansions together (the first three terms of both expansions) to try and get the expansion for $f(x)$, but I am not sure if that is correct. I know I can do it by finding the derivatives of $f(x)$ and then just writing out the Maclaurin series, but I need to do it by using the parent functions and their expansions.

Comment: Why don't you just take your Taylor expansion for $e^{-x}$ and divide those infinite terms by x?

Comment: Yes, please do that!   After all, the series you wrote for $\frac{1}{x}$ is centered at $1$ and not $0$.

Comment: @NeoPlato I tried that but I am not sure if it's correct either.

Comment: $1/x-1+x/2-x^2/6+x^3/24-...$ converges to $e^{-x}/x$ for all $x\ne0$

Comment: Technically, isn't it a Laurent series?

Comment: You may as well try to find a similar power series as $1/x = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$!!

Comment: @zugzug I am not sure but most likely if centered at 0 it must inevitably be a Laurent series since the function has a pole at 0

Comment: @zugzug A Laurent series centered at $0$ is defined by: $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k\cdot x^k$, whereas a Maclaurin series is defined by: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\cdot x^k$

Comment: @MathematicallyEncrypted : Isn't your answer below just a Laurent series with $a_{-1}=1$ and $a_k=0$ for $k < -1$?

Comment: Technically speaking, any Taylor series can be turned into a Laurent series supposing that $a_k=0$, for $k<0$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Maclaurin series (Taylor series centered around $0$) of $e^x$:
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k!\cdot x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\cdot\frac{x^k}{k!\cdot x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\cdot\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}$$
Which can be expanded into:
$$\frac{1}{x}-1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^3}{24}-\frac{x^4}{120}+\cdots$$
The series representation has the same boundaries as $\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$: it's defined for all $|x|>0$ and $x\not\to -\infty$.